# Scraping NFL.com fantasy football projections using Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am looking to scrape the data on http://fantasy.nfl.com/research/projections into a simple pandas data frame, using Python's Beautiful Soup and requests libraries. I have used the following code:

```
a = "http://fantasy.nfl.com/research/projections"
req = requests.get(a)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text,"html.parser")
```

My aim is to scrape data for each of the positions and on a week-by-week basis. However the data returned from this is the 2018 season total. There doesn't appear to be any splits. How can I split it down so that the data I scrape is what is shown if the Week 1 option is chosen (for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily by parsing the URL's from the pagination section.

You can see that they have the endpoint `statWeek=`. We can just plug in the week we want and get the results from that page. Here is an examples script that grabs the player name, fantasy points (projected?) and week number for the first 25 weeks, and saves it in a Pandas dataframe.

```
def get_weekly_players(res):
    res_list = list() 
    week = url.split('statWeek=')[1]
    player_rows = res.find_all('tr')
    for row in player_rows:
        name = row.find('a', 'playerCard')
        points = row.find('td', 'stat_30')
        if name and points:
            res_list.append((name.text, float(points.text), int(week)))
    return res_list
```

We define a function to extract the desired information from the parsed HTML.

Then, we simply loop through the week numbers and extend the tuple results to a list.

```
all_res = list()
for week in range(0, 25):
    url = '''http://fantasy.nfl.com/research/projections?position=O&sort=projectedPts&statCategory=projectedStats&statSeason=2018&statType=weekProjectedStats&statWeek={}'''.format(week)
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"html.parser")
    res = get_weekly_players(soup)
    all_res.extend(res)
```

Then we can pass the results to a Pandas dataframe constructor and we are done.

```
player_df = pd.DataFrame(all_res, columns=['player', 'points', 'week'])
```

You can see we have the results for all 25 weeks.

```
player_df.describe()
          points      week
count   625.00000   625.000000
mean    3.22840     12.000000
std     0.37989     7.216878
min     2.14000     0.000000
25%     3.17000     6.000000
50%     3.30000     12.000000
75%     3.40000     18.000000
max     3.66000     24.000000
```

Comment: Thanks @Steven! I have a couple of questions. "player_rows" is undefined in the function, but I'm guessing it's a list? Would I be right to assume that the function should take an extra argument of "soup", which is then somehow split into the "player_rows" variable. I'm unsure how to do this last step though?

Comment: Oops, forgot to add a step there. I edited the post. Let me know if this works for you (you can accept the answer).